# Void Pointer Error

Tags: c++, c, void-pointers

```
#include <iostream>

func(void *ptr)
{
 *ptr = NULL;          
}

int main()
{
 void *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));   
 func(ptr);
 return 0;   
}
```

Can Some one Help me in Resolving this. I want to assign NULL to this Pointer. Do Not make any changes in Main().

Comment: Why do you need this? To change pointer in function call, you need to pass pointer to pointer. But I afraid you don't even understand usual pointers.

Comment: In C you should not cast the return of `malloc` (or any function returning a void pointer). You only need that in C++.

Comment: void func(void *ptr)
{
 ptr = NULL;          
}

int main()
{
 void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));   
 func(ptr);
 return 0;   
}

Comment: By the way, unless you `free` the allocated memory before calling `func` (after it's fixed) you will have a memory leak.

Comment: to make changes in ptr declared in main...do like this                            void func(void **ptr)
{
 *ptr = NULL;          
}

int main()
{
 void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));   
 func(&ptr);
 return 0;   
}

Comment: *(&ptr) = NULL;  this is wht i was expecting.. some other way !! Hope fullyyy

Comment: hint: since you are using c++, take a look at references

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are passed by value.  So change `func(void *ptr)` to `func(void **ptr)` and pass in `func(&ptr)`

Comment: Actually, once the signature is fixed, it should be `*ptr = NULL;`

Comment: Well, if the OP passes the pointer by reference, then it indeed should be `*ptr = NULL`. :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: agree with you.

Comment: *(&ptr) = NULL; ............

Comment: Pointers are passed by value : NOT NECESSARY

Answer (score 0):

use `ptr = NULL;` and don't cast the return of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Dont cast because C malloc returns void pointer by default. Then the program should be good to run

Comment: Noo.. Still the same thing !!! I am not able to understand.. cant i do the *ptr = NULL. no one has given exxact reason.. instead of ignoring